# Devel 'Display Query Log' not showing any queries

Tags: database, debugging

I've enabled 'Display Query Log' in the Devel Settings but I don't see any logged at the bottom of my page when I load a page. I just get 'Queries exceeding 5 ms are highlighted.'.

I'm running Drupal on PHP 5.3.2 with a mySQL database.

The issue is present in both the Admin theme and my custom theme.

Other Devel outputs seem to display fine.

Any ideas why the queries aren't showing?

Comment: May be your queries are getting executed before 5 ms. :) try with 1ms. and ' Collect query info' is also checked ?

Comment: I've tried this. Doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: worst case scenario uninstall the devel module and install it again.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check 'Collect query info' in the devel settings: /admin/settings/devel

Otherwise no logs can be shown.

Answer (score 1):

The admin module routinely breaks this. Try disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

I often forget to set appropriate user permissions on the devel module when I re-enable it.

Comment: Probably not in OP's case, where he can see the 'Queries exceeding 5 ms are highlighted.' line.
But others might not see any output at all, because of the permissions you mention.